# Sorting TList<object> (ntiers) with ThenBy

Tags: c#, list, sorting, asp.net-3.5

We are using nTiers and I have this list of objects that i need to sort by a property but then by another property,i have the following but i cant figure out how to to the `ThenBy`, I have seen examples with `List<object>` but not with `TList<object>`.

```
TList<Client> clients = service.GetClientsById(cid);
clients.Sort("ClientOrder");
```

but then i need to sort it by the `ClientName`. I saw an example in another post using LINQ, but i cant get this to work like that (example below),which would allow me to do a `ThenBy`

```
List<Order> SortedList = objListOrder.OrderBy(o=>o.OrderDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Comparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) class with `List.Sort`:

```
clients.Sort(new Comparison<Client>(
    (client1, client2) =>
    {
        // compare dates
        int result = client1.OrderDate.CompareTo(client2.OrderDate);
        // if dates are equal (result = 0)
        if(result == 0)
            // return the comparison of client names
            return client1.ClientName.CompareTo(client2.ClientName);
        else
            // otherwise return dates comparison
            return result;
    })
);
```

(In the example above, handling null values is skipped but it must be included in a real work).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `ThenBy<Client>` *before* you call `ToList<Client>`:

```
List<Order> sortedList =
    clients.OrderBy(o => o.ClientOrder)
           .ThenBy(o => o.ClientName)
           .ToList();
```

[`ThenBy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby.aspx) works *only* on [`IOrderedEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534852.aspx)s `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`s are the return type from [`OrderBy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx), but once you call `ToList<T>`, it's not an `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` anymore, but a `List<T>` and [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) doesn't implement `IOrderedEnumerable<T>`.