# Sort or Order TList<myobject>

Tags: c#, list, sorting, tlist

I have a `TList<SKU>` that I want to sort by the SKU object id's. Below is how the list is obtained from the database (base code from the third party vendor being used).

`TList<SKU> skuList = skuAdmin.GetByProductID(this.itemId);` *the itemId is an integer value representing the product id.

I want to sort this list based on the the `SKUID` attribute that every `SKU` has. I've been looking at the sorts & orders for `List<>` but I can't seem to find a solution that I can tailor to my need.

This: [Sorting TList<object> (ntiers) with ThenBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847112/sorting-tlistobject-ntiers-with-thenby) was probably the closest I could find to what I want to do.

What I want to do is return the `SKU` list item with the lowest the `SKUID` can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order the whole list.. you can do:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => x.SKUID).ToList();
```

If you want the lowest one, you order them, then take the first one:

```
var first = list.OrderBy(x => x.SKUID).FirstOrDefault(); 
// will be null or the SKU with lowest SKUID.
```

Comment: The orderby isn't available for a `TList`

Comment: What is this `TList`? Is it a generic list?

Comment: Of sorts I believe,  I haven't worked with them often or really at all.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? You may need to include `using System.Linq` to make it work.

Comment: I am using .net 4.0. You were correct in saying that I needed to add `using System.Linq`.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
TList<SKU> skuList = skuAdmin.GetByProductID(this.itemId).OrderBy(item=> item.Id).ToList(); // Or OrderByDescending() but you said you want lowest to highest, so OrderBy should be used.
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the SKUID's are unique then something like this should return the lowest one or null if the list is empty:

```
SKU lowestSKU = skuList.Find(x => x.SKUID == skuList.Min<SKU>(y => y.SKUID));
```